# Does putting view on top of each other affect listeners?

Tags: android

I am making an app where we can drag a view over another view. The below view has a touch listener but it gets missed up when I move the top view over it. It hangs a little bit but the top view has no problems.

Hence my question is, does listeners get affected when we have a view on top of another view ?

Comment: well yes they are affected.The click will be received by the top view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do.

Check following example of `OnTouchListener`:

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) 
    {

    // do some thing
        return true;  // when you return true here event will not propagate to views those
    // are in lower hierarchy. Means inside views will not be able to consume onFling event
    }
```